# EF Core 5 + Sql Server: slow query

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

EF Core created a paginated query that searches data in a navigation property.
The generated raw query is:

```
DECLARE @__p_1 varchar(40) = '%Ordine Rilasciato%';
DECLARE @__p_2 int = 0;
DECLARE @__p_3 int = 20;

SELECT *
FROM [RDA] AS [r]
LEFT JOIN [StatoRDA] AS [s] ON (([r].[IdSocieta] = [s].[IdSocieta]) AND ([r].[CodiceStato] = [s].[CodiceStato])) AND ([r].[CodiceStatoOrigine] = [s].[CodiceStatoOrigine])
WHERE LOWER([s].[DescrizioneStato]) LIKE @__p_1
ORDER BY LOWER([s].[DescrizioneStato])
OFFSET @__p_2 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_3 ROWS ONLY
```

this query takes up to 40 seconds to elaborate, but if I omit the declaration like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [RDA] AS [r]
LEFT JOIN [StatoRDA] AS [s] ON (([r].[IdSocieta] = [s].[IdSocieta]) AND ([r].[CodiceStato] = [s].[CodiceStato])) AND ([r].[CodiceStatoOrigine] = [s].[CodiceStatoOrigine])
WHERE LOWER([s].[DescrizioneStato]) LIKE '%Ordine Rilasciato%'
ORDER BY LOWER([s].[DescrizioneStato])
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

the elaboration is immediate.

Since the first query is generated by EF I have no control on it.

Query code:

```
var qry = myContext.Rda
    .Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.StatoRda.DescrizioneStato.ToLower(), "%" + item.Valore + "%"))
    .OrderBy(x => x.StatoRda.DescrizioneStato.ToLower()
    .Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
```

Both filter and order are made on a related table

Comment: Looks like it is parameters sniffing https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/

Comment: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: My dba said it's possible that  the variables in the sort part cause the query to take a wrong execution plan. He add OPTION(RECOMPILE) in the end of the query and now it works like a charm. Should I implement this statement into EF Query or maybe Sql Server side?

Comment: [Command interception to add query hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#example-command-interception-to-add-query-hints)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I will probably do it, but I'm asking why a "normal" query should create so many issues. I made the same query in EF6 and It wasn't affected to any sort of problem. It would be possible to tell to EF CORE to create query without using variable declarations?

Comment: Using parameters in general speeds up the work with the database, saves cache and eliminates sql injection. But sometimes it has a negative effect, as in your case. Here only hint will help. There is no standard way to disable the parameters in EF, because of the threat of sql injections.